# Combine two prometheus queries

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to calculate requested memory for specific node for all pods which are in phase 'running'. So I tried this query

```
sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{node="node_name1", 
resource="memory"}) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 * on(instance, namespace, pod) 
group_left(phase) kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}.
```

It gives an `Empty query result`.
But when I run the above queries separately, I see that there are running pods on that node. So I tried another approach like this

```
sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{node="node_name1", 
resource="memory", kube_pod_status_phase="Running"})/1024/1024/1024
```

And the result was the same, an `Empty query result`. So how can I calculate the requested memory for all running pods in the specific Node?

Comment: Your first approach is generally right, you just have problems matching metrics labels. Read [Many-to-one](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches).

Comment: Add labels set of independent evaluations of parts of your expression to question.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. I put the parentheses on wrong place. The metric should look like this
`sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{node="node_name1",  resource="memory"} / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 * on(instance, namespace, pod)  group_left(phase) kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"})`

That way it envelop both queries.